# How to optimize fluentbit in kubernetes?

Tags: logging, devops, fluent-bit

i want to ask or maybe we can discuss together.

So i use fluentbit as a log scapper on my kubernetes cluster, but when in backend service have a lot of process, fluentbit will work faster, and the resources used are higher for scrape logs and sometimes nodes often die suddenly.

How to solve this problem? because I want to fluentbit working well when trafic process high

**Notes:** this is my fluentbit input config

```
Buffer_Chunk_Size 150k
Buffer_Max_Size   150k
Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
Skip_Long_Lines   Off
Skip_Empty_Lines  On
Refresh_Interval  10
Read_from_head    true
```

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
Buffer_Chunk_Size 1M
Buffer_Max_Size   1M
```

and if you are using v2.0 add:

```
threaded on
```

also make sure that your flush interval is set to `1` second (SERVICE section)